# Check the render method of 'PodCastScreen' React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-redux

I am building a player app in react native and I have this error pop up. I have never seen this error. Ive tried clearing cache and checking my imports and exports.

Frist set of code is from the PodCastScreen Component and the second set of code is from the Player Component.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { Player } from './PodcastLayers/Player';

export const TRACKS = [
{
title: 'Stressed Out',
artist: 'Twenty One Pilots',
PodcastArtUrl: "http://36.media.tumblr.com/14e9a12cd4dca7a3c3c4fe178b607d27/tumblr_nlott6SmIh1ta3rfmo1_1280.jpg",
audioUrl: "http://russprince.com/hobbies/files/13%20Beethoven%20-%20Fur%20Elise.mp3",
},
{
title: 'Love Yourself',
artist: 'Justin Bieber',
PodcastArtUrl: "http://arrestedmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/JB_Purpose-digital-deluxe-album-cover_lr.jpg",
audioUrl: 'http://oranslectio.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/39-15-mozart_-adagio-fugue-in-c-minor-k-546.mp3',
},
{
title: 'Hotline Bling',
artist: 'Drake',
PodcastArtUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Drake_-_Hotline_Bling.png',
audioUrl: 'http://russprince.com/hobbies/files/13%20Beethoven%20-%20Fur%20Elise.mp3',
},
];

class PodCastScreen extends React.Component{
render() {
return (

<Player tracks={TRACKS} /> )
}
}

export default PodCastScreen;
```

Player Component Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';
import PodcastArt from './PodcastArt';
import PodcastDetails from './PodcastDetails';
import { SeekBar } from './SeekBar';
import Controls from './Controls';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

class Player extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  paused: true,
  totalLength: 1,
  currentPosition: 0,
  selectedTrack: 0,
  repeatOn: false,
  shuffleOn: false,
};
 }

 setDuration(data) {
// console.log(totalLength);
this.setState({totalLength: Math.floor(data.duration)});
}

setTime(data) {
//console.log(data);
this.setState({currentPosition: Math.floor(data.currentTime)});
}

seek(time) {
time = Math.round(time);
this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(time);
this.setState({
  currentPosition: time,
  paused: false,
});
}

onBack() {
if (this.state.currentPosition < 10 && this.state.selectedTrack > 0)          {
  this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(0);
  this.setState({ isChanging: true });
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({
    currentPosition: 0,
    paused: false,
    totalLength: 1,
    isChanging: false,
    selectedTrack: this.state.selectedTrack - 1,
  }), 0);
} else {
  this.refs.audioElement.seek(0);
  this.setState({
    currentPosition: 0,
  });
}
}

onForward() {
if (this.state.selectedTrack < this.props.tracks.length - 1) {
  this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(0);
  this.setState({ isChanging: true });
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({
    currentPosition: 0,
    totalLength: 1,
    paused: false,
    isChanging: false,
    selectedTrack: this.state.selectedTrack + 1,
  }), 0);
}
}



render() {
const track = this.props.tracks[this.state.selectedTrack];
const video = this.state.isChanging ? null : (
  <Video source={{uri: track.audioUrl}} // Can be a URL or a local file.
    ref="audioElement"
    paused={this.state.paused}               // Pauses playback entirely.
    resizeMode="cover"           // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
    repeat={true}                // Repeat forever.
    onLoadStart={this.loadStart} // Callback when video starts to load
    onLoad={this.setDuration.bind(this)}    // Callback when video loads
    onProgress={this.setTime.bind(this)}    // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
    onEnd={this.onEnd}           // Callback when playback finishes
    onError={this.videoError}    // Callback when video cannot be loaded
    style={styles.audioElement} />
);

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar hidden={true} />
    <Header message="Playing From Charts" />
    <PodcastArt url={track.PodcastArtUrl} />
    <PodcastDetails title={track.title} artist={track.artist} />
    <SeekBar
      onSeek={this.seek.bind(this)}
      trackLength={this.state.totalLength}
      onSlidingStart={() => this.setState({paused: true})}
      currentPosition={this.state.currentPosition} />
    <Controls
      onPressRepeat={() => this.setState({repeatOn : !this.state.repeatOn})}
      repeatOn={this.state.repeatOn}
      shuffleOn={this.state.shuffleOn}
      forwardDisabled={this.state.selectedTrack === this.props.tracks.length - 1}
      onPressShuffle={() => this.setState({shuffleOn: !this.state.shuffleOn})}
      onPressPlay={() => this.setState({paused: false})}
      onPressPause={() => this.setState({paused: true})}
      onBack={this.onBack.bind(this)}
      onForward={this.onForward.bind(this)}
      paused={this.state.paused}/>
    {video}
  </View>
);
}
}

export default Player;

const styles = {
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'rgb(4,4,4)',
},
audioElement: {
height: 0,
width: 0,
}
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `Player` component?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I have added the Player component

Comment: The solution below should solve your issue, but also check the exports of other components. It would be great if you could add your code here [snack](http://snack.expo.io) and add the link to the question

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue with your Player component or an incorrect import. Try just:

```
import Player from './PodcastLayers/Player';
```

Comment: Already tried this and I get the same render error if I don't put the brackets for Player